# Get original image files through Podio API

Tags: podio

Currently we can retrieve (image) files at 'extra large' with 520px. We need the full resolution of the original. I know it's there because when viewing a image files, in the Podio interface, I can choose 'Download original' and I get a 4500px file downloaded. 
How can I get the original file through the API?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to retrieve various sizes depending on the use of the image.  You can read more about the `Files` API endpoint [here](https://developers.podio.com/doc/files).  For images attached to Items, you should be able to retrieve a 520 x ?? px version.

**Update:** The API does allow you to retrieve the raw image in its original size.  The URL that will allow you to do this is `https://api.podio.com/file/<file_id>/raw`.  Using the Javascript API you should be able to make this request following the documentation [here](http://podio.github.io/podio-js/api-requests/).

Comment: Hi Kenneth, we currently use the 520px files but need a higher resolution. Is there a way I can get the original (e.g. 4500px width) that was uploaded?

Comment: Hi Kenneth, in addition to my previous reply I did some testing with GlobliFlow. They use the php API and are able to retrieve the original image. Ik made a pdf with the large image. So it is possible. We use the javascript library. Is this a limitation of javascript API or is there another way to retrieve the full resolution image?

Comment: Hey Ron, I've amended my answer in a way that will hopefully answer your question more completely.